# If I click outside of Material UI Autocomplete input field then all text of input field got vanished

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material Ui Autocomplete component. So if you write something on that box and then click anywhere outside that input field your input field texts just got cleared out.How can I solve this problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function Filter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="filter-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      filterOptions={x => x}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Custom filter" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: watch the included image for better understanding]

Comment: please show detail code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just able to solve the problem I was facing. Just adding clearOnBlur={false} prop inside Autocomplete Component do the job.